# Oracle/JPA fk in table has no corresponding pk in another table

Tags: oracle, jpa

I have a strange case in Oracle DB that I have entries in one table that have FK to another table, but this id not exists there.

Pseudocode:

```
create table table1 {
 ID VARCHAR2(20) PK,
 TABLE2_ID VARCHAR2(20) FK -- exactly FOREIGN KEY(TABLE2_ID) REFERENCES TABLE2(ID)
}

create table table2 {
  ID VARCHAR2(20) PK,
}
```

I found in the database such entries in TABLE1 that have TABLE2_ID set to specific value, but such entries not exist in TABLE2.

```
Select g.id from TABLE1 g WHERE g.TABLE2_ID ='9kMHvJ0'; --returns 3 rows
Select k.id from TABLE2 k WHERE k.id='9kMHvJ0'; --returns 0 rows

select g.id, k.id from VS_USER.TABLE1 g --returns 0 rows
JOIN TABLE2 k ON g.TABLE2_ID = k.ID
WHERE g.TABLE2_ID ='9kMHvJ0';
```

I checked if constraint works by trying to add the same ID (non-existing one) in another rows and I'm getting ORA-02291, so it works fine and sees that this entry not exist.

Additionally, when I fetch data from table1 via JPA I'm getting error:
`Unable to find com.blablabla.Table2Entity with id 9kMHvJ0; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.blablabla.Table2Entity with id 9kMHvJ0"`

**Questions**

1. How is it possible that our database has such inconsistency? How someone could create it?
2. How to prevent getting error from JPA described above?

Comment: You should have a foreign key constraint added to your database. The column should also be declared not null. If you don't know these things get some help from someone familiar with correct database design.

Comment: @K.Nicholas this is pseudocode as I wrote. Foreign key is created properly and columns with foreign key don't have to be not null.